# Bjt connected as diode

Tags: bjt

I have a dumb question. My textbook says \$\beta I_B\$ current flows into the collector terminal.
Isn't Collector-Base path shorted by the external wire? Since base and collector regions are semiconductors, they offer very high resistance compared to the external wire path. How can more current flow into the collector terminal of the bjt compared to the external shorted wire?

[image]

In below two diagrams I put resistors. Which connection is correct and why?

[image]

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxLe99.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: My semiconductors physics is really bad but this might be something more easily explained from the perspective of electron flow. It would make sense if the base controls the number of electrons entering the emitter terminal, then get swept across the base junction to the collector before they can leave the device through the base terminal.

Comment: @DKNguyen I followed till  `It would make sense if the base controls electrons entering the emitter terminal ` rest I'm not able to get :(

Comment: The rest is just how BJTs work and why the base junction is thin and why current is able to pass through the reverse biased PN junction

Comment: You think in term of conduction current. But transistor action is mainly due to diffusion current. That's where the magic happen. And it happens in semiconductors, not in metals - like a copper wire joining base and collector.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to think of Bjt/diodes in terms of resistance alone since they are nonlinear devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At collector terminal, the current coming from the right side has two
>   options: take the high resistive semiconductor path or the least
>   resistive wire path. Why more current takes the semiconductor path is
>   still confusing me ;(

But the wire is in *series* with the base so I'm not clear on what your reasoning is here.

Looking into that wire from the collector node, there isn't a low resistance path around the collector to the emitter terminal, there is a low resistance path *to the base terminal*.

So, *both* paths are through the semiconductor - one path is into the collector, the other path is into the base.

Comment: One path is `Collector-Base-Emitter`, other path is `Wire-Base-Emitter`. Since resistance of `Collector` region is greater than the `Wire`, I don't get why more current goes through `Collector` region..

Comment: If I replace collector, base, emitter with 3 resistors, then the wire path is effectively shorting the collector resistor...

Comment: @beccaboo, I don't see why you would say the wire path is shorting the 'collector' resistor. For that to be true, the wire would need to be in *parallel* with that resistor. But it isn't in parallel with that resistor. The wire goes to the 'base' resistor so it's the 'base' resistor that is in parallel with the 'collector' resistor due to the wire. Draw the 3 resistor circuit you have in mind.

Comment: Alfred thank you but how can base resistor be in parallel with collector resistor? I've updated the question with the resistors arrangement which I feel is correct. Please see...

Comment: @beccaboo, shouldn't the three resistors be connected together at a common (internal) point? Think of a Y connected network of three resistors.

Comment: Oh looks my basics are bad. I thought Emitter, Base, Collector regions are in series(180 degrees) physically without external connections. Do you mean a T shape, like, vertical base resistor? I'll draw it quick and update.. one sec very interestingXD

Comment: I've updated the question with Y connected network. With this connection I see how base resistor is in parallel with the collector resistor. Still wonder how vertical resistor is justified for the base while horizontal resistors are used for the other two regions...

Comment: Also with the vertical base resistance, we can think that the base offers more resistance and limits the current. So everything makes sense XD

Comment: I get it. Resistor goes in the direction of current flow. You're awesome! Thank you so much:))

Answer (score 1):

It is no different than using small base current to control a larger collector current. The emitter current is base current plus collector current, Ie = Ib + Ic. It's just that collector current is beta times base current, so Ic = beta * Ib. So, Ie = (beta+1) * Ib. For whatever the beta happens to be at this bias point where Vb equals Vc because they are shorted.

Comment: Why does more current flow through the np junction though? If the base current was limited, this would make sense, but its not (compared to the collector current).

Comment: At collector terminal, the current coming from the right side has two options: take the high resistive semiconductor path or the least resistive wire path. Why more current takes the semiconductor path is still confusing me ;(

Comment: The collector is only less conductive to the emitter when V1 is very low, approx. 0.5v (transistor is off.) As V1 > 0.6v, the base is 'turned on' somewhat, allowing current to also flow from collector to emitter. For each 1mA given to the base, the collector will sink \$I_B\cdot\beta\$.  The base-emitter *is* a diode, so voltage can't go much higher than 0.7v as it is sinking current.

Comment: @rdtsc when the base is 'turned on' is it okay to think that collector region has less resistance than the external metal wire?

Comment: Not really - the wire is just giving current to the base-emitter, which allows the collector-emitter to sink more current than the base-emitter. But no current will flow without that wire.